# User input with single quote not working with prepared sql

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a textarea for inserting/update text to sql but inserting text with single quote always insert into DB something like : `shaq o'neal = shaq o\'neal`
How to avoid this?

```
$stmt = $cnx->prepare( "INSERT INTO information (information, infoDate, status, dateCreated) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?)" );
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $infoWithoutSingleQuote , $today , $status, $dateCreated);
$info = mysqli_real_escape_string($cnx, $_POST['newInfo']) ;
$infoWithoutSingleQuote = str_replace("'" , "''", $info);
```

I have tried this and also without `str_replace();`

Comment: The answer is simple remove the last two lines. Why do you even have them there?

Comment: Is not good to use mysqli_real_escape_string() before insert data into database? Anyway it works your answer but it's safe?

Comment: It's just pointless.

Answer (score 2):

You are destroying the data yourself. Remove the harmful `mysqli_real_escape_string` and you should be ok.

```
$stmt = $cnx->prepare( "INSERT INTO information (information, infoDate, status, dateCreated) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?)" );
$stmt->bind_param('ssss',  $_POST['newInfo'], $today , $status, $dateCreated);
```

As long as you bind all input and never put variables directly into SQL query your code will be safe and you don't need to escape anything.